# I am confused. If haar functions have integral zero, shouldn't every linear combination of them have integral zero?

Tags: real-analysis

I think I have a really silly question that I just can't think about the right way. So, in my EE class we learned about haar functions. They have integral equal to zero and form an orthonormal basis for functions on R. That is we can write every function as $f(x)=\sum\langle f,h_k\rangle h_k(x)$ where we know that $\int h_k(x) dx=0$. But then, isn't it true that $\int f(x)dx = 
\sum \langle f,h_k\rangle \int h_k(x)dx = \sum \langle f,h_k\rangle 0 = 0$? For a simple example - to not have to worry about swapping the integral and sum, what if $f$ is the characteristic function on the unit interval?

Now, I get that we can do something like: let $f$ be a function and let $g$ be the characteristic function for the set where $f\neq 0$. Then we have:
$\int f(x)dx = \sum \langle f,h_k\rangle \int g(x) h_k(x)dx$ and then this destroys the integral zero property of the haars. But what I really want to know is why what I said in the paragraph above is wrong.

EDIT:
Maybe the whole problem is with swapping the sum and integral. But the professor (and the book, too, I think) also did stuff like:
$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \sum \langle f,h_k\rangle \langle f,h_k\rangle
$$
which is justified by being able to swap the sum and integral.

Comment: I don't think so. No haar function is constant.

Comment: Nor is $1$ a sine or cosine function, but we still need it when doing Fourier analysis. Without it, all Fourier series necessarily have zero integral. To put it in EE terms: in general, an AC signal has a DC part, but it's still an AC signal.

Comment: For a general $L^2$ function, the integral doesn't exist. And for the subspace $L^1\cap L^2$, where the integral exists, integration is not continuous with respect to the $L^2$ topology.

Comment: I see. So is the problem really just with swapping the sum and integral?

Comment: Semiclassical, I understand, but 1 is not one of the haars and is not needed in the expansion. (At least not when you are doing things on the real line - you need it when you are making a basis for functions defined on an interval.)

Comment: It starts with writing down the integral. But even if the integral is valid, interchanging summation and integration is only valid if the series expansion is also valid in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. For the inner product, we can interchange summation and inner product because the inner product is continuous.

Comment: Daniel Fischer, thank you very much, I get it now. I see, for example, I can use Cauchy--Schwartz to say the the integral in the inner product is absolutely convergent, so then I can swap the sum and integral. But in the case of the integral of the haar, I can't do this.  Does this sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The haar functions $h_k$ are a orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  So, if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then we can write
$f=\sum\langle f,h_k\rangle h_k$ or more precisely: 
$$f=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\langle f,h_k\rangle h_k(x)$$
Please, note two important things: $f$ must be in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and the limit above is in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ norm (topology).

It is true that, for all $k$, $\int h_k dx = 0$. However, 
$$ \int f dx = \int \left(  \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\langle f,h_k\rangle h_k(x)  \right) dx \neq \lim_{n \to \infty}\int \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \langle f,h_k\rangle h_k(x) \right)dx$$
because the integral is NOT a continuous functional in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ norm (topology).

In fact (as Daniel Fischer pointed out in the comments), in general, if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the integral of $f$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much! And now, if someone asks: prove that integration is not continuous in L^2, I can say: haar functions. lol.